# Create a custom component to create display design options in admin and design option dropdown and selected will be displayed on product page

Tags: graphql, magento2.4.6, db-schema, magento-graphql, patch-data

Create a custom component to add/edit/delete and view the detail of design information into admin. Associate the multiple design option to product and show selected design option product detail page.

Create following fields in given table:
Table name: design
design_id int 10 primary key
design_name varchar 50 unique
design_status tinyint 1
design_created_at  datetime
design_updated_at datetime

design_option attribute should create to save multiple design options  to show while product detail shows to the user.